# Making a Regex Django URL Token Optional

Tags: regex, django, url, django-urls

You have a URL which accepts a `first_name` and `last_name` in Django:

```
('^(?P<first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<last_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/$','some_method'),
```

How would you include the OPTIONAL URL token of `title`, without creating any new lines. What I mean by this is, in an ideal scenario:

```
#A regex constant
OP_REGEX = r'THIS IS OPTIONAL<title>[a-z]'
#Ideal URL
('^(?P<first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<last_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/OP_REGEX/$','some_method'),
```

Is this possible without creating a new line i.e.

```
('^(?P<first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<last_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<title>[a-zA-Z]+)/$','some_method'),
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
('^(?P<first_name>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<last_name>[a-zA-Z]+)(?:/(?P<title>[a-zA-Z]+))?/$','some_method'),
```

Don't forget to give `title` a default value in the view.

Comment: thanks for that. How would I make a URL of JUST optional '`titles`'? i.e. `(?:/(?P<title1>[a-zA-Z]+))?(?:/(?P<title2>[a-zA-Z]+))?` thanks for any help

Comment: Note that the ?: is important in the outer group. Without it, the URL will work properly when navigated to, but reverse() won't notice the argument inside.

Comment: More info about this in the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#nested-arguments).

Answer (score 1):

In case your are looking for multiple optional arguments, without any required ones, just omit "/" at the beginning, such as:

```
re_path(r'^view(?:/(?P<dummy1>[a-zA-Z]+))?(?:/(?P<dummy2>[a-zA-Z]+))?(?:/(?P<dummy3>[a-zA-Z]+))?/$', views.MyView.as_view(), name='myname'),
```

which you can browse at:

```
http://localhost:8000/view/?dummy1=value1&dummy2=value2&dummy3=value3
```