# Optional named groups Python re

Tags: python, regex, django

In the Django urls I need an optional named group. This conf without arguments raised an 404 exception:

```
r'^list_cv/(?P<category>[\d]+)?/$'
```

How to make optional named group?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a Regex Django URL Token Optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325433/making-a-regex-django-url-token-optional)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works this way to me:

```
r'^list_cv/(?:(?P<category>[\w+])/)?$'
```

#### EDIT:

Comparing to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270540/629685) the difference is in the repetition match.

`(?:(?P<category>[\w+])/)?$` vs original `(?:(?P<category>[\w+])?/)$`.

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad Tayseer!

Answer (score 4):

The last slash should be part of the optional RE, and the RE should be like

```
r'^list_cv/(?:(?P<category>[\w+])?/)$'
```

I didn't test it, though.

Comment: This was not really working, but the third answers was working http://stackoverflow.com/a/8271065/548558 with this r'^list_cv/(?:(?P<category>[\w+])/)?$'

Answer (score 4):

I find that it's more legible to create a separate url pattern for the url without the named group.

```
url(r'^list_cv/$', my_view),
url(r'^list_cv/(?P<category>[\d]+)/$', my_view),
```