# django url name lookup

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I have three url pattern match to the same url name

```
url(r'^report/newreport/(?P<number>\w+)/$', 'report.views.newreport',name='report_newreport'),  
url(r'^report/newreport/(?P<number>\w+)/(?P<edit>\w+)/$', 'report.views.newreport',name='report_newreport'),        
url(r'^report/newreport/$', 'report.views.newreport',name='report_newreport'),
```

When I tried to use 'url' to get full url like this

```
<td><a href='{% url report_newreport report.applicationnumber %} ' target='_blank' >{{task.applicationnumber}}</a> <br/>
```

I got an error

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'report_newreport' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Is that because I matched three urls to one url name? I think this shoudl be fixed by matching these three patterns to three different url names. Is that other way I can fix this error

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to have multiple views with the same name? Have you tried giving them different names?

Comment: Also, assuming "ccicreport" is supposed to be "report" like the others, you could possibly merge them into a single regex following the example of [Making a Regex Django URL Token Optional](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2325433).

Comment: @perelman Yes, it was a typo :), updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the fact that `report.applicationnumber` is not generating a value: `with arguments '('',)'` in the error message indicates that `report.applicationnumber`'s value is empty in which case the `url` tag attempts to match the URL pattern `^report/newreport//$` which does not exist in your URL list.