# Django URL Multiple-Routes Pattern Not Injective

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to include optional URL patterns in my Django project by adapting the multiple-routes pattern explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14351174/3734991).

In my `urls.py` file I have the following patterns.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)\/?$', View.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<section>[-\w]+)\/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)\/?$', View.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<section>[-\w]+)\/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)\/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)\/?$',View.as_view()),
]
```

The parameters `section`, `tag`, and `slug` correspond to model fields. So a HTTP request to `/foo/bar/baz` returns a model instance with a "foo" section, "bar" tag, and "baz" slug. Not all model instances have a `section` or `tag`, those parameters are optional.

If you think about the URL dispatcher as a function with a domain of URLs and a codomain of model instances, the pattern I'm using isn't an injective function. `/baz`, `/foo/baz`, and `/foo/bar/baz` return the same model instance, but only the last URL should return the model instance.

In short, how do I configure my `urlpatterns` to return my foo-bar-baz model if, and only if, the requested URL is `/foo/bar/baz`?

Comment: why don't you just accept the url as one regex and then split it with / and do what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be much easier to deal with in the view.  In your view, I'd look at the request and if the URI is of the wrong form, then issue a redirect to the right URI.  That's going to be much easier than trying to force this into the URL dispatcher.

Comment: You're right, I've been playing around with overwriting the `get_object` method in `SingleObjectMixin` and it looks like that's going to get me the desired behavior. Thanks!