# Get Current Url Without Parameters in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have a url like below:

```
url(r'^board/(?P<pk>\d+)$', board_crud, name='board_update'),
```

I want to get current view 'board' without parameters so that i can redirect to it.

I want to redirect to current view(without param) in same view(with param).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Judging by the url you have provided, it doesn't look like you can redirect to the same view without the parameter (since it is compulsory).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to do something like this:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^board/$', board_redirect, name='board_redirect'),
url(r'^board/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', board_crud, name='board_update'),
```

> PS: Note the ending `/`, it's a good idea to always end the url
>   patterns with a forward slash, for consistency (except cases where you
>   are return a url like `sitemap.xml` for example).

Then, you would need to create a view like this:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import Foo

def board_redirect(request):
    latest = Foo.objects.values('pk').order_by('-date').first()
    return redirect('board_update', pk=latest['pk'])
```

The queryset would define the logic you want to implement. I don't have more info on your application. In this example you would always show the "latest" object based on a "date" field. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Exactly i am doing that, but i have alot of models that need crud, and i cannot enter all the views one by one in : 
return redirect('board_redirect')