# set a parameter with default value to route url in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, url, router

Hy all!

I'm new to python / django and I came across a problem that I can not solve. I have a route configured for the site's home (1) and a route configured for categories (2):

```
1) url(r'^$', IndexView().home, name='home')
2) url(r'^categoria/(?P<path>.*)/$', IndexView().by_category, name='by_category')
```

I need to set my home url to open a category by default, something like ***www.mysite.com/c=defaul_category***

I tried in some ways, including: ***url (r '^ / (? P  \ w +) / $', IndexView (). Home, name = 'home')***. But I know it's incorrect.

So... I have no idea how to do this. Could someone help me?
Thank you

Comment: Item 1) corrected

Answer (score 1):

You should tell django that *path* in by_category url may be omitted. You have at least two options here:

1 - create one more url without *path* but with passed `path` variable as 3-rd argument in `url`:

```
url(r'^/(?P<c=vinhos>\w+)/$', IndexView().home, name='home')
url(r'^categoria/(?P<path>.*)/$', IndexView().by_category, name='by_category')
url(r'^categoria/$', IndexView().by_category,
    {'path': 'default_path'}, name='default_category')
```

2 - change regex pattern to make it possible to omit path parameter. Here `|` (or sign) added in the end of path group:

```
url(r'^categoria/(?P<path>.*|)/$', IndexView().by_category, name='by_category')
```

More about omitting url parameters [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Comment: Thanks! but... I could not make this idea work for me.

Comment: @GustavoAdolfo i didnt understand what this means: `IndexView().by_category`. Maybe you should change it to `IndexView.as_view()`