# Django Page not found error event if path is correct

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I'm new to `Django framework` using 2.1 version, I have trouble using optional parameters in `urls.py`

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('myblog/', include('myblog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Appname : myblog

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views
app_name = 'myblog' #FOR NAMESPACE ISSUE THIS IS REQUIRED
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^test_view/<mode>/(?:blog-(?P<blog_id>\d+)/)?$', views.test_view)
]
```

myblog view.py

```
def test_view(request, mode, blog_id):
    return HttpResponse('ss')
```

myblog template

```
<button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'myblog:test_view' 'create' 1 %}'">Create New Blog</button>
```

### ERROR

```
IN TEMPLATE : 
NoReverseMatch at /myblog/
Reverse for 'test_view' not found. 'test_view' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

ADD WHILE ACCESSING URL DIRECTLY `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myblog/test_view/create/1/` I GET
`PAGE NOT FOUND`

### IT IS TO BE NOTED THAT AS PER THE DOCUMENTATION GIVEN IN [DJANGO DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#nested-arguments) I HAD MAKE SAME CHANGES BUT STILL I GET THAT ERROR

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Please remove the "noise": change uppercase into lowercase, etc.

Comment: No need to shout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify url name using `name` argument:

```
re_path(r'^test_view/(?P<mode>\w+)/(?:blog-(?P<blog_id>\d+)/)?$', views.test_view, name='test_view')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work here is the error i got `Reverse for 'test_view' with arguments '('create', 1)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['myblog\\/test_view/<mode>/(?:blog-(?P<blog_id>\\d+)/)?$']`

Comment: @PavanWebbeez check update. Fix regexp here `<mode>`.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much. It works !.  IS `?P` a optional parameter.

Comment: @PavanWebbeez no it just means named group.

Comment: so i django how can i specify a parameter as optional

Comment: @PavanWebbeez you need `?:`, check this queston https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters