# Django Rest Framework url_pattern of @action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to pass instance id after last / of my @action name method, and I seriously have no idea how...

I have a UserViewSet, which url to access list is : **/users/**, then i have action called **favorite_posts**, which is **detail=False** because I'm filtering by current logged user, and the action refer to user posts, I wanna be able to pass the post_id like **/users/favorite_posts/post_id/**, because in this case it's more friendly to me than **/users/1/favorite_posts/** which I could obtain setting **detail=True**.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `/posts/<id>/`? Otherwise you have two paths to the same resource. And I'd suggest to invent something like '/home/' root url for obtaining anything related to _current user_. `/users/` + `/users/<id>/` resulting with anything else then list of users and user by id produce ambiguity and misunderstanding of common rest approaches.

Comment: I have manytomany relation inside user to posts, and from this action I wanted to be able to just manipulate that one list, in /posts/ i dont have path to user favorite posts to that only one path to this resource. It seemed to me more logic to manipulate user list on user path, than on post.

Comment: Yes, you've discovered `favorite_posts` **list with post ids**, now you want to reach **specific post by id**. Post is a separate entity which is expected to be discovered at `/posts/<id>/`.

Answer (score 12):

You can include parameters in your url pattern and have `user_id` passed to your method like this:

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=False, url_path='favorite_posts/(?P<user_id>\d+)', url_name='favorite-posts')
def get_favorite_post(self, request, user_id):
    # Do something
    return Response({...})
```

Comment: Is there any method to url_path='favorite_posts/(?P<user_id>\d+)' mandatory?
I have 'GET', 'POST' and 'DELETE' there, and for get I wanna get list, and pass id only for del and post.

Comment: @slqq I'm not sure if I followed. You can use any method you like. As for your other question above about having `user_id` optional, you need to modify the regex in `url_pattern` to something like this: `favorite_posts/(?P<user_id>\d*)`. This way `user_id` can be between zero and any number of digits.

Comment: @slqq still, I recommend separating your methods for list and details, instead of having one action method taking care of different things.

Comment: When I use 'favorite_posts/(?P<user_id>\d*)' i lose chance to not pass this argument, it's required in this way, even I set user_id=False in method arguments.

Answer (score 5):

You can use it like this:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='req/(?P<post_id>\d+)')
```

and get post_id in your method like this: `kwargs.get('post_id')` or just pass `post_id` directly to your method.

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='req/(?P<post_id>\d+)')
def get_post(request, post_id):
     .....
```

Comment: Thats working but now I must always pass the 'post_id' and I wanted to return list on get, and pass it only on delete.

Comment: You want to pass it on all viewSet methods?

Comment: No, no, only on this action, i'm trying to make this <post_id> not a must, so if I don't pass it would be nice to get just a list.

Comment: give a default value to post_id and see how it goes? `get_post(request, post_id='')`

Comment: I tried but getting 404 anyway, it look like @action decorator raise it before.

Comment: maybe we should modify regex to be optional. check this: `req(?:/(?P<post_id>\d+))?` . also remember to pass post_id in method arguments optional too.

Comment: With this new regex nothing work, lost retrieve by id, tried to point two urlpatterns to this action but one for delete, other for get but that doesnt work too.

Comment: check this link, it may be usefull [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters/14351174)

Answer (score 0):

This only works with r because its regex use `url_path=r'favorite_posts/(?P<user_id>\d+)', url_name='favorite-posts'`