# Making URL to accept parameters as optional. Non Capturing

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I want to make my url to accept the optional parameters only when given. I am unable to make the parameters optional/non-capturing.

```
re_path(r'^users/(?:(?P<sort_by>\d+)/)?$', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
```

I want this url to accept a  `slug` field only when provided to the view. How can I do this?
It is showing an error

```
Reverse for 'user_list' with keyword arguments '{'sort_by': 'username'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/users/(?:(?P<sort_by>\\d+)/)?$']
```

when I passed sort_by='username'

Comment: See [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Comment: have seen it. Not able to comprehend. Can you help?

Comment: Ok, try `r'^users/(?P<slug>[^/]*)'` or `r'^users(?:/(?P<slug>[^/]+))?`

Comment: i just want [a-z] and _ in my url.  like sort_by=is_superuser

Comment: So, `r'^users(?:/(?P<slug>[a-z_]+))?`?

Comment: something like  admin/users/is_superuser   or    admin/users/date_created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep your url to:

```
re_path(r'^users/$', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list'),
```

And then in your template use

```
   <a href="{% url 'user_list' %}?sort_by=username">Sort</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you  tell me how to sort data using that? It looks messy but yeah it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would create 2 URLs:

```
path('users/<str:sort_by>', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='user_list_by_user'),
path('users', views.UserListView.as_view(), {'sort_by': 'default_sort_you_use'}, name='user_list'),
```

Then you can call the appropriate URL and always have a `sort_by` value in the view.

Comment: thanks man. I was using slug. will it makes a differene if I pass <str> or <slug>?

Comment: Sure, you can use <slug>