# How to add an optional slug in a Django Url

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to add an optional Stackoverlow like slug to my urls in Django

```
path(
    r"item/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>",
    ItemDetailView.as_view(),
    name="item_detail",
),
```

How do I make the slug optional so that it works in all three cases:

1. item/1
2. item/1/
3. item/1/slug

Comment: As far as I know there is no option to treat parameters in url as optional. In this case you need to create two paths linked with one view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `re_path`

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^item/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)(?:/(?P<slug>[-\w]+))?/$', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="item_detail"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is using different paths:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/<int:pk>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="item_detail"),
    path('item/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="item_detail"),
]
```