# How to define optional query parameters in Django?

Tags: python, django

here i got one endpoint to receive multiple query parameters namely `first_name`, `last_name`. `location` and i need the endpoint to be able to handle following scenarios

- all the 3 param's
- 1 param
- 2 param's

And i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24610817/10516773) but still i got `404` when provide one query parameter, only works when all the parameters are given.

`urls.py`

```
re_path(r'^project_config/(?P<product>\w+|)/(?P<project_id>\w+|)/(?P<project_name>\w+|)/$',
            views.results, name='config')
```

And view

```
    def results(request, product, project_id, project_name):
        response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
        print(product)
        print(project_name)
        return HttpResponse(response % project_id)
```

How can allow url to accept optional query parameters ?

Comment: Would it not be better to use a GET parameter instead of putting them inside the url?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/14351174/5600452

Comment: If the number of parameters is dynamic, then it is often better to work with a *querystring* instead.

Comment: parameters are not completely dynamic, it's a combination of three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments using query-parameter try this

URL

```
re_path(r'^project_config/',views.results, name='config')

# http://127.0.0.1:8000/project_config/?product=1&project_id=2&project_name=foo
```

Views

```
def results(request):
    
    queryprms = request.GET
    product = queryprms.get('product')
    project_id = queryprms.get('project_id')
    project_name = queryprms.get('project_name')
    
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    
    # set your combination
    if product and project_id and project_name:
        # do some thing
    if product and project_id:
        # do some thing
    
    # so on

    return HttpResponse(response % project_id)
```