# django url accepts None

Tags: python, django

My url is like this below. it accepts `/tracks/1` ,`/tracks/2`

```
path('tracks/<int:pk>',views.tracks,name='tracks'),
```

However I want to accept `/tracks` without pk value.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Just add another route to the `urlpatterns` that returns the same view (or any view you want)

```
path('tracks/<int:pk>',views.tracks,name='tracks'),
path('tracks/',views.your_view ,name='name'),
```