# How can i define default value for urls parameters in Django?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-3.2

###### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Staff

class StaffListView(ListView):
    model = Staff
    template_name = 'staff/staff_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Staff.objects.filter(websites__path=self.kwargs['web'])
```

###### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<str:web>/staff/', include('staff.urls')),
    # I want to set web=chemical, if url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/staff
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django optional url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters)

Comment: @PacketLoss No, it did not work for me.

Comment: In what way does it not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

With Django URL you cannot do that. But I have a cheat way. You can use `middlewares` > Check the URL if this one is a URL validated with empty param > redirect it to the correct URL.

Sample:

```
def redirect_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # In here I write a sample with a basic check, you can use regex to check.
        if request.path == "/staff": 
            return redirect('/chemical/staff')
        response = get_response(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use RedirectView ?

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<str:web>/staff/', include('staff.urls')),
    path('staff', StaffRedirectView.as_view()),
]

# in views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


class StaffRedirectView(RedirectView):

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "/chemical" + self.request.get_full_path()
```

I think, this idea can be work for your case

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('staff/', include('staff.urls'),kwargs={'web':''}),
    path('<str:web>/staff/', include('staff.urls')),
]
```

###### staff.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.StaffListView.as_view())
]
```