# Try next view in Django URL dispatcher

Tags: python, django

We have the following URL configuration in Django.

Django will try to match the URL with the rules down below. Once it finds a match, it will use the appropriate view and lookup the object in the model.

The thing is, once it finds a match in the URL pattern, it will match the view. But once the object in the view can't be found, it will return a page not found (404) error.

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<slug:category>/<slug:editor>/', views.ArticleByThemeView.as_view(), name='articles_by_editor'),
    path('articles/<slug:category>/<slug:theme>/', views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='articles_by_theme')
]
```

`views.py`

```
class ArticleByThemeView(ListView):
    """
    List all articles by a certain theme; "World War 2".
    """
    model = Article
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Check if the theme_slug matches a theme
            theme = ArticleTheme.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['theme_slug'])
        except ArticleTheme.DoesNotExist:
            # Theme does not exist, slug must be an article_slug
            return redirect(
                'article_detail',
                category_slug=category_slug
                article_slug=theme_slug
            )
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    """
    Detailview for a certain article
    """
    model = Article

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
            Article,
            category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'],
            slug=self.kwargs['article_slug']
        )
```

We have the following URL patterns, we can sort articles either by the editor or by theme. We do this to create a logical URL structure for SEO purposes.

Is there any way we can redirect to another view once the object isn't found?

Can we modify the `dispatch` method to return to the URL patterns and find the following matching rule?

Comment: Can you share your views?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14351048

Comment: Multiple routes pointing to the same view, never thought about this. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

What about redirection like this:

```py
def articles_by_editor(request, category, editor):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(category=category, editor=editor)
        # return article
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        # redirect to another view
        return redirect('articles_by_theme', category=category)
```

Comment: Even though this sounds like a great solution, it ends up in a redirect loop. Not entirely sure why, I get a series of 302 in my console...

Comment: It does work however when I redirect to the home page ie. ('/')

Comment: do you redirect in `articles_by_theme` too ?

Comment: Even though we redirect to 'articles_by_theme', it catches a redirect to itself. I'll update the question with some more context. Im currently overriding dispatch method on a listview.

Comment: Just updated the answer to include the Class Based views I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [suggestion from Sunderam Dubey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282588/try-next-view-in-django-url-dispatcher/75287049#comment132842132_75282588), I wrote a function view, which uses two different routes to the same view.

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<slug:category>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_theme_or_detail_view, name='article_by_theme'),
    path('articles/<slug:category>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_theme_or_detail_view, name='article_detail')

]
```

`views.py`:

```
def article_theme_or_detail_view(
    request,
    category_slug,
    slug=None
):
    """
    This view could either be for a theme view or detailview,
    depending on the slug.
    """
    try:
        # Check if the slug represents a theme
        theme = ArticleTheme.objects.get(slug=slug)
        article_list = Article.object.filter(theme=theme)
        
        # Add context
        context = {
            'theme': theme,
            'article_list': article_list
        }

        # Render the template with context
        return render(
            request,
            'article_by_theme.html',
            context
        )
    except ArticleTheme.DoesNotExists:
        # The theme does not exist so the slug must be for a detail view
        context = {
            article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
        }

        return render(
            request,
            'article_detail.html',
            context
        )
```

To do:

- Remove one of the URL routes