# Django url which accept both with parameter or without

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I want to accept both urls with and without parameters, such as `/top/` `/top/1`

I tried a few patterns:

```
path('top/<int:pk>/', views.top, name='top_edit'),
path('top/(<int:pk>)/', views.top, name='top_edit'),
path('top/(<int:pk>)/$', views.top, name='top_edit'),


def top(request: HttpRequest,pk = None) -> HttpResponse:
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

It accept `/top/1` however `/top/` is not accepted.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pk = None` in view Try this,

```py
def top(request: HttpRequest,pk = '') -> HttpResponse:
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the URL without the parameter too:

```
path('top/<int:pk>/', views.top, name='top_edit'),
path('top/(<int:pk>)/', views.top, name='top_edit'),
path('top/(<int:pk>)/$', views.top, name='top_edit'),
path('top/', views.top, name='top'),


def top(request: HttpRequest,pk = None) -> HttpResponse:
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make it optional i.e. both `top/` and `top/1` should be accepted with one url path and one view.

You can make the URL pattern optional by adding a question mark `?` after the parameter in the URL pattern so:

```py
path('top/(?P<pk>\d+)?/', views.top, name='top_edit'),
```

In this pattern, `(?P<pk>\d+)?` is the optional parameter. The `?` at the end of the pattern makes the entire group optional, so that it matches either zero or one times. The `(?P<pk>\d+)` part of the pattern is the regular expression for matching an integer value.

Then with this URL pattern, your view function should be able to handle both `/top/` and `/top/1` URLs so:

```py
def top(request: HttpRequest, pk=None) -> HttpResponse
    # when pk is None (i.e. /top/ URL)
    if pk is None:
        # Do something for the /top/ URL
    else:
        # Do something for the /top/1 URL
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

You can further see the question: [Django optional URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14351048)