# how to prevent the extra slashes comin in the url of the browser

Tags: django

urls.py

```
url(r'^kebreading/$', 'KEBReading1',name="kebreading"),
url(r'^kebreading/(?P<param>\w*)/(?P<date>\w*)/(?P<year>\w*)/(?P<month>\w*)/$', kEBReading1',name="kebreading")
```

i have a  view which i pass 5 parameters to it. and the same view is being called when i dont pass any parameter. but five slashes gets appended to the url in the browser even wen i don pass any parameters. how to prevent this happening???

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regexp `?` sign to create an optional group and use `?:` so Django do not pass this group as an `*arg` parameter

Something like :

```
url(r'^kebreading/(?:(?P<param>\w*)/(?P<date>\w*)/(?P<year>\w*)/(?P<month>\w*)/)?$', kEBReading1',name="kebreading")
```

There is a similar question [#2325433](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325433/making-a-regex-django-url-token-optional)