# Django url tag with several parameters

Tags: django, url, parameters

Can I write follow statement in django template?

```
<a href="{% url 'settings:update' controll.id mode='change' %}">{{ controll.s_name }}</a>
```

If it possible then what will be in url.py and views.py

Comment: yes . its possible . you can find many examples in SO as well as in google .

Comment: What is correct request for search or mb some link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325433/making-a-regex-django-url-token-optional This is one of example.

Comment: I tred follow regexp url(r'^(?P<controller_id>\d+)/(?P<mode>[a-zA-Z]+)/$', views.update, name='update') and def update(request, controller_id,mode) but I have exception "Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!"